# google_drive gem not working "LoadError: cannot load such file -- google_drive"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

So this is my first time using a new API for rails. The particular gem I am trying to use today is this.
https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/master/README.md

so after installing it manually to one of my projects on rails,

```
$ gem install google_drive
```

I tried to test it out on Ruby console by just typing

```
require 'google_drive'
```

but the error that returned to me "LoadError: cannot load such file -- google_drive."

I also have tried installing this gem, which too didn't help

```
gem install google-api-client
```

I am trying to learn how to update my google sheets through one of my web page forms ... but this simple step has got me stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manually installed the gem by calling `gem install 'google_drive'` and afterwards calling `require 'google_drive'` in an IRB session, that works fine.

Does your Rails project's Gemfile include the gem (`gem 'google_drive'`)? Rails will only load the gems specified in that file.

Comment: Oh, so I have to actually add in the gem in my gem file even if I installed it manually?  Damn! Will try in a bit

Comment: Yes, `rails c` will only load the gems that you specifically specified inside your Gemfile.